# How do I get the comments added to a comment in the in the Box REST API?

Tags: box-api, boxapiv2

How do I get the comments added to a comment in the in the Box REST API?

For example, how would I return the comments (marked in red) for the comment (marked in black)?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They should be included in the list comments on a file. The only difference is that the reply comments will have their `is_reply_comment` field set to true.

Note that the ordering of the returned comments is important. Since replies can only be one level deep, a reply comment is always associated with the first non-reply comment above it.

Here's a sample response including a comment and a reply to the first comment:

```
GET https://api.box.com/2.0/files/28785720644/comments

{
  "total_count": 2,
  "offset": 0,
  "limit": 100,
  "entries": [
    {
      "type": "comment",
      "id": "63003535",
      "is_reply_comment": false,
      "message": "First message",
      "created_by": {
        "type": "user",
        "id": "221860571",
        "name": "Name",
        "login": "login@gmail.com"
      },
      "created_at": "2015-04-14T17:49:07-07:00"
    },
    {
      "type": "comment",
      "id": "63003537",
      "is_reply_comment": true,
      "message": "Reply message",
      "created_by": {
        "type": "user",
        "id": "221860571",
        "name": "Name",
        "login": "login@gmail.com"
      },
      "created_at": "2015-04-14T17:49:07-07:00"
    }
  ]
}
```